# How can I create a deb package with 'folders' and files in it

Tags: package-management, software-installation, deb

I have some files that need to be installed in `/usr/share/wallpapers` when the deb package is installed. I have created the changelog, control files etc. However I don't know how to put the files in it. I have tried using `dh_install` however I get:

> cp can not stat directory debian/tmp//usr/share/wallpapers

How can I go about extracting the wallpapers from the deb file to `/usr/share/wallpapers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders are handled in the same way as files. Add a line to the `your_application.install` file, like `your_wallpapers /usr/share/`, to install the your_wallpapers folder into the directory `/usr/share/`.

Comment: What do i have in the rules file

Comment: ok, pasting code in a comment does not work, but are you sure the directory `/usr/share/wallpapers` exists? if not, you should create a folder `wallpapers` and install it into `/usr/share`

Comment: Do I need any special entries for the .install file

Comment: No, it is basically a list of files and directories, followed by the locations they should be copied into. My guess is that something is wrong there

Comment: Yes The directory exists. I am wondering if my rules file needs to make reference to my .install file as my packages now doesnt contain anything apart from some /usr/doc files which arent even in the source code diretory. I think something may be wrong. Are there any source code examples of installing files as I find it easier to use these.

Comment: you could make a "primitive" deb installer to check, following this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717, to check if everything works, to close out a number of causes.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I followed the instructions and build the deb and all is working now.